# How to set the return type of function in superclass to be type of last subclass?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to convert an existing library to explictly define return types. It essentially looks like this:

```js
export class Base {
  public foo() {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Base2 extends Base {
  public bar() {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Base3 extends Base2 {
  public zii() {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Base4 extends Base3 {
  public per() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

My task is to explicitly set the return type of functions that return `this` to the final subclass. My naive solution was to do the following:

```js
export class Base<T> {
  public foo(): T {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Base2<T> extends Base<T> {
  public bar(): T {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Base3<T> extends Base2<T> {
  public zii(): T {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Base4 extends Base3<Base4> {
  public per() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

But I get multiple of these errors:

```
- error TS2322: Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'this'.
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? If so, how do I refactor the code to accomplish this?

---

### Additional context

I've tried to avoid complicating this question because the use case for this question is not so simple. I accept that within Typescript, typing each function's return type with `this` is the optimal solution. However, my intention is to crosspile this code using the [jsii](https://github.com/aws/jsii) library into a Python API. The code is functional as is, but the real issue is that the language servers don't pick up methods for autocomplete from subclasses when chaining methods, i.e.:

```py
b = Base4()
b.bar().  # bar is a method from `Base2` that returns a `Base2` object
#       ^-autocomplete doesn't show methods from `Base3` and `Base4`
```

My hope is that if I explictly type the superclasses' functions' return types to be of `Base4`, the language server can correctly show the full function list that it should have access to.

Comment: I think that it might be easier to help you with a larger example. I don't understand your last point as the methods are all available as you desire with your current behavior with the LSP.

Comment: `const obj = new Base4().` - shows autocomplete from all subclasses. Honestly, I don't understand either. Why do you use generic `T`? `T` is not related to `this` type at all

Comment: sigh, do all SO volunteers nowadays just read code and then type comments? 
The last code block is in `Python`. And if you haven't grasped that, then it shows you haven't read the surrounding context and therefore are unable to answer my question. And this question is now moot anyways, I've started exploring other paths to get the resulting structure I desire.

Comment: Many people sharing their code with syntax errors, or just pseudo code

Answer (score -1):

The concept that you need is called a `MyType` or `SelfType` in Type Theory. You're in luck, TypeScript is one of the few mainstream programming languages that have them, together with [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.SelfTy.html). In [TypeScript, they are called *`this` types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types):

```typescript
export class Base {
  public foo(): this {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Base2 extends Base {
  public bar(): this {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Base3 extends Base2 {
  public zii(): this {
    return this;
  }
}

export class Base4 extends Base3 {
  public per(): this {
    return this;
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oAcCuAjEAlsNAGYD2ZAFAJQBc0ALgBYExoYYBOCD2nAdoxYQA3OmgBfVFNShIMeBAQAmaAgAeDBPwAmCxCnE58RaLjCca9Zq0Mdo3XgKGsxGKTLlQ4iAMxrNbT0fJVV2LDxCYgAvAgIrFzZxLh4+QRtRcQ9UWXBvRQQAFgCtXX0lf3DjKKwESzpEuw5HNMS3SWkc4DJ+CAYzaABeaH4EAHcQopoxWR6+6GB6AuLh3AA6cipqMSA)

Comment: Sorry if I'm mistaken, but `this` sets the type to the class it's in, right? I think what I was asking, what if I wanted all those `this` statements to be specifically of type `Base4`?

Comment: Well, you can't, because that would be lying. If I say `const b = new Base(); const c = b.foo()`, then `c` is most definitely *not* an instance of `Base4`, so typing it as `Base4` would be a type error.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing what I'm intending? I really only ever want to instantiate `Base4` objects but `Base`, `Base2`, `Base3` have important methods that I want to pass onto `Base4`.

Comment: I'm still not clear what, *exactly*, it is that you want to do, and why my solution does not do what you need. Can you provide a *specific* [mre] that *clearly* demonstrates the kind of problem you are talking about? My code in my answer passes every single test from your question, so I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'd like to create the equivalent of a `Base4` object that obtains methods from `Base`, `Base2`, `Base3` whose methods I'd like to have an explicit return type of `Base4`, and not a return type of `Base`, `Base2`, `Base3`. I don't believe your code satisfies this query of mine. I'd like to know if what I'm asking is possible since my TS knowledge is limited.

Comment: Let me ask you a second time: please show me the *exact* test code you are using which fails with my solution. If you don't tell me what the problem is, then I cannot fix it. It works fine in my tests, and it works fine with the code you posted in the question. So, if it is not working for you, that means that the code in your question does not accurately represent your real problem, and since I cannot read your mind, there is no way for me to know what the problem might be.

Comment: I've added additional context to my original question. IMO the original question was my attempt to distill the problem I was trying to solve, so I hope the additional info provides some clarity.

Comment: The problems with the new code you added to the question do not have anything to do with what you are asking about. The problem is that `b` is not declared anywhere and that `Base4` has no call signature, but neither of those two things has anything to do with the return types of the methods. If you change the first line to `const b = new Base4();`, then it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you're reading the context I wrote. This is not a question with a simple test case definition. With no offense, I don't think you're reading or understanding the question I posted. Nor am I confident in my ability to write it a way for you to understand. Feel free to discontinue your effort on this question. Thanks for your time.